# Как правильно выложить портфолио на GitHub?

Tags: github, frontend

Как лучше разместить своё портфолио на GitHub? Вот например я недавно сверстал сайт, прикрутил мини сервер который наполняет его товаром, но на GitHub ведь сервер не запустишь, а если запускать просто HTML страницу, то не будет товара и некоторых функций.

Или стоит просто в описание добавить чтобы качали Git и запускали у себя? А прямо на GitHub просто сверстанную страницу показать?

Comment: знающим человекам я думаю достаточно просто взглянуть на код, чтобы понять, как он работает.
А так посмотрите в сторону heroku и подобному софту.

Comment: Чтобы прямо свёрстанную страницу показать, есть github.io. А вообще да, гитхаб предназначен для кода, а не для страничек

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub — это портфолио вашего *кода*. Туда потенциальный работодатель может посмотреть, чтобы понять, какой код вы пишете, в каких проектах участвуете.

Для портфолио с динамическими сайтами нужен традиционный хостинг. Для нетребовательных демонстрационных сайтов без каких-либо посетителей хватит самых дешёвых хостингов (возможно, даже бесплатных). GitHub хостит только статические странички.

Отмечу, что по возможности стоит демонстрировать реальные работающие проекты, в которых вы приняли участие, а не поделки на коленке. Если вы кодируете back-end, то гораздо интереснее будет код. Если вы кодируете front-end или дизайните страницы, то работающий сайт уже будет важен.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что показывать работодателю "интернет-магазин" это хорошая идея. Существует множество таких же, но уже готовых решений, к примеру, тот же [VirtueMart](https://www.virtuemart.net/). Кроме того, никто не любит вчитываться, язык бизнеса это наглядность. Маловероятно, что кто-то дойдет дальше регистрации на подобном ресурсе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В [этом](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/tripolskypetr.github.io) репозитории автор поднимает вопрос неверного оформления большинства портфолио программистов на Github Pages. Повсеместное использование Bootstrap с наполнением [текстом-рыбой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) делает написание очередной поделки контрпродуктивным. Как решение проблемы предлагается создать [PWA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) с максимальной компактностью, приметностью и актуальными использованными инструментами.